# lodash filter and exclude value

Tags: lodash

I am using lodash _.filter function. While filtering, I want to remove an element if it same as its successive element. In this code, display

Here is the scenario,

```
fObj=[1,2,3]
 template=[{"v":1,"d":"ABC","disabled":true},{"v":2,"d":"xyz","disabled":true},{"v":3,"d":"PQR","disabled":false},{"v":4,"d":"lmn","disabled":true}]
arr = _.filter( template, function ( item )
{
    return item.disabled === true || fObj.indexOf( item.vm ) !== -1;
});
```

This is a kind of parent child, assume ABC,XYZ are parent. Parents which doesn;t have children has to be removed.
Since XYZ has a child PQR, i should display both. There is no relationship between parent and child.
We have to assume, when two successive elements have disabled=true, I want to remove both.

2 parents(abc and lmn) which doesn;t have child should be removed

Answer (score 0):

I made an example for you

```
var arr = _.filter( template, function ( item, index )
{
    if(item.needToBeRemoved) {
         return false;
    } else {
        var isNotTheLastElement = index < (template.length - 1);
        if(isNotTheLastElement) {
            var nextItem = template[index+1];
            if(item.disabled && nextItem.disabled) {
                nextItem.needToBeRemoved = true;
                return false
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
});
```

Here is the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/W4QfJ/2999/)

Comment: you want me to use _.reject instead of _.filter

Comment: you can achieve the same thing with filter. I just used reject because it made more sense to me. I will be nice and update the example with filter to you :)

Comment: Now you have the same thing but using filter instead.

Comment: ya filter would be good option,as someother logic in the function is depend on filter

Comment: I guess not working as expected, but Iam not sure, how does this work incase of last element is disabled.

Comment: I think we need to add this condition too,                var prevItem = m_data.visualSurvey.surveyFeature[idx].surveyRefData[index-1];
               if(item.disabled && prevItem.disabled === false) {
                //return false;
               }

Comment: I don't think we need to change anything on that answer. If you check the jsFiddle on the answer you you will see that it works just fine :)

Comment: where r u comparing the template elements with that of fobj

Comment: i saw the fiddle output which gives PQR and LMN. but should that be XYZ and PQR , ABC and LMN parent doesn;t have child's and they need to be removed